# What scriptures describing holding breath for hours before chanting the Sahasrakshi Mantra?

Tags: vaishnavism, mantras, practice, sri-vaishnava

The Sri Vaishnava sect is divided into two sub-sexts, Thenkalais and Vadakalais.  One of the issues they disagree on is whether the chanting of the Pranavam in the Ashtakshari Mantra requires Upanayanam to chant, or whether Samashrayanam is sufficient.  But both Thenkalais and Vadakalais agree that when the Ashtakshari Mantra is shorn of both the Pranavam and the dative case ending, it is free for anyone to chant, even by people who have done neither Samashrayanam nor Upanayanam.  In the nine minute mark of [this video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Thgs9ZU3QbU), the Sri Vaishnava lecturer U. Ve. A. S. Rajagopalan Swami compares this with things that do require Upadesam:

> [For] Ashtaksharam you need an Upadesam, and you need an Upadesam on certain kinds of things.  There is one Mantram called Sahasrakshi Mala Mantram.  **To tell that one once, you have to hold your breath for several hours.**. Not minutes or seconds, several hours.  Can we do that one?

A. S. Rajagopalan Swami goes on to say that the Sahasrakshi Mala Mantra has Swarga as its fruit.  But I’m interested in the part in bold.  My question is, what scriptures describe having to hold your breath for several hours before chanting the Sahasrakshi Mala Mantra?

So far all I could find is [this webpage](http://www.gurudiksha.com/yantra/rare-yantra/sahasrakshi-yantra/) selling a “Sahasrakshi Yantra” associated with the chanting of a “Maa Sahasrakshi Mantra”, which I assume is some kind of Shakta Mantra.  But I’m not sure whether that’s the same Mantra being discussed above.

Comment: If you link to holding of breath with yogic texts, its actually establishing ourself in natural breathless stage than holding of breath. We cant hold breath for several hours but rather we can be in breathlessness for several hours. In Kundalini Yoga, in natural breathless stage, there's a mantra to chant to activiate when breath suspends. So your question from Vaishnava perspective is good and nice!

Comment: @AkshayS Holding of breath could have several meanings  like sitting quietly in silence  and in concentration , before chanting.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar when we sit quietly breath will run still. The tantra in chanting a mantra is when internal breathing operates, if we chant mantra at that time, it has immediate results!!! Yes as you say it could have another meaning, but holding of breath before chanting in all possibility could imply Sushumna operation!

Comment: @SwiftPushkar The way A.S. Rajagopalan says “Can we do that one?” it sounds like he’s discussing something that’s impossible for ordinary humans.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree you on that no doubt  , was just replying to comment. And as usual its my guess .:-)